# How can i subtract a decimal value from a Timespan?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2017

I currently am trying to subtract a value from a difference which is a timespan.  this difference represents how many hours a person has worked.  the value is the break and lunch added. This will be subtracted from the difference.

When i try to send data to the database an error generates "unable to cast object of type System.TimeSpan "

```
DateTime b = DateTime.Parse(StartTimeddl.Text);
DateTime c = DateTime.Parse(EndTimeddl.Text);
decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(BreakDurationddl.Text);
decimal f = Convert.ToDecimal(LunchDurationddl.Text);
decimal totalBreak = f + d;
decimal fullBreakTime = 0;
TimeSpan difference = (c.Subtract(b));
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Total_Hours_Day", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = difference.Hours;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
fullBreakTime = totalBreak + Convert.ToDecimal(difference);
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the total difference in hours between `b` and `c`, and then add the total break time in hours?

Comment: I am trying to subtract the totalbreak time from the total difference. eg if someone has worked 8 hours a day and had 1 hour break it would be a total of 7 @RufusL

Comment: it will be minutes. 20 would be 20minutes etc @Haldo

Comment: number values are in StartTimeddl & EndTimeddl  eg 5 , 10 , 15 , 20. these are saved to the database in decimal(18,0)

Comment: Also you might consider using the `NumericUpDown` control for getting whole numbers from the user. It has a `decimal Value` property that represents the number the user entered. No need for validation in your code!

Comment: sorry getting mixxed up.  the StartTimeddl & EndTimeddl has values like 09:00 09:30 apolgies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're getting is on the line where you try to convert the `TimeSpan` to a decimal. Instead, you should convert the `TotalHours` of the `TimeSpan`:

```
fullBreakTime = totalBreak + Convert.ToDecimal(difference.TotalHours);
```

But from your comment,

> I am trying to subtract the totalbreak time from the total difference. eg if someone has worked 8 hours a day and had 1 hour break it would be a total of 7

you can simply calculate the total number of hours worked and then subtract the break times (note I'm working with `double` instead of `decimal` here since that's what `TimeSpan` uses for `TotalHours`):

```
double hoursLogged = (c - b).TotalHours;  // or (b-c).Duration().TotalHours()
double totalBreak = f + d;
double hoursWorked = hoursLogged - totalBreak;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to convert Timespan to Decimal, instead it should be

```
Convert.ToDecimal(difference.TotalHours)
```